# importing sql file into a database using wamp

Tags: mysql, wamp

I tried importing my yyy.sql file ( a large file) into xxx database through wampserver. I copied yyy.sql file to C: drive and through mysql console
mysql> use xxx
mysql>source C:\yyy.sql

when I execute these commands it seems its reading each row.
after that it gives 
mysql>
and when I check the xxx database it's showing empty.
what's wrong?

Comment: did you try phpMyAdmin in wamp ? you can also import sql there.

Comment: yeah.. since its a large file I am importing through console window.

Comment: in you post you didnt connect to mysql with username password and host? mysql -u {DB-USER-NAME} -p {DB-NAME} < {db.file.sql path}

Comment: To Import a large file through phpMyAdmin
Find the config.inc.php file located in the phpmyadmin directory. In my case it is located here:

1 C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\config.inc.php
2 Find the line with $cfg['UploadDir'] on it and update it to:
3 $cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';
4 Create a directory called ‘upload’ within the phpmyadmin directory.
5 C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\upload\
Then place the large sql file that you are trying to import into the new upload directory. You can now import.

Comment: Sadly, after giving php.ini gigabytes of max file size and memory, it imported no faster than a regular SQL import. I wouldn't reocmmend PhpMyAdmin unelss you're only deal with a smallish database. I cannot recommend the command line solution below enough, I can import hundreds of megabytes of SQL data a minute. (500MB takes less than 2 minutes)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Option 1;**  PHPMyAdmin

```
1. left click wamp -> phpmyadmin
2. select database then click import (top right)
3. locate the database and click go.
```

**Option 2;** Using the command line.

The easiest way to import a sql file into a database in WAMP, using command line is as follows:

```
1. Open Command Prompt (CMD - DOS) get into the mysql folder, which in my case works like this
C:\> cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.51b\bin

2. Then use this command to fire up MySQL
   This line basically connects you to the mysql database of your choice.
   (-p for password if you have one)
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.51b\bin> mysql.exe -use databasename -u username -p

3. To make things easier, copy the SQL file into the same folder as mysql.exe, and then run this
mysql> source myfilename.sql;
```

Comment: when I use mysql>show tables; in console its clearly showing tables what I needed but through a browser localhost/phpmyadmin in xxx database its empty

Comment: have you tried to create a new table in the database in phpMyAdmin ? or try to repair database with the command mysqlcheck -r databasename and check if that fix the problem.

Comment: It can also be a predefined USER issue. may be that user is not present in your phpMyAdmin try to check it IMPORTANT

Comment: I followed the method you mentioned through cmd.After last step the window kept giving lines "Query OK, 1 row affected<0.00 sec>" when I check the xxx database its showing only a sample table which I created through phpMyAdmin as you mentioned. Its not showing the file I imported. :'(

Comment: Or is there a method like directly pasting the sql file in database folder ??

Comment: do you have only structure or data is also present in your sql file? and did you check which user are you using for phpMyAdmin sql requests ?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I had a 200 MB highly compressed SQL dump which would take hours via the normal Navicat import method. I ran it through your command line method and it took less than 60 seconds.

Comment: For whatever reason, 2 years later, I could not connect to localhost using your example, I did finally manage by connecting using this script instead: "mysql -use database -uroot -p" and then typing the password after it prompts you.

Answer (score -2):

1. OPEN your filename.sql in NOTEPAD.....
2. COPY all content..... left
3. Click wamp>phpmyadmin.....
4. CREATE new Database.....
5. and Click on SQL tab and PASTE the content.....
6. then Click on GO..... Hurray!

   you have done