# Restore wordpress from local copy

Tags: wordpress

I have a local wordpress backup which is a copy of the main dir from the previous webhost. 
I runned the site using wampserver but when I tried to open the index page it said: "Error establishing a database connection".

I think this is because the database is not imported in phpMyAdmin. How can I make this work so I can access the site?

Comment: first of all you need a DB backup which I guess you don't have?

Comment: If you have a database, you should check this link (option 1 is the is the easiest) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310424/importing-sql-file-into-a-database-using-wamp

Comment: @Alex No I do not think so I only have the public_html, is there anything I can do to still get the site working? I do not need the old users anymore. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not only users stored in database. Also post, pages content an so on. So if you don't need none of them, just pass connection to new clear database. Settings stored in config file in root folder of wordpress

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress database stores all of the site content - Posts, Pages, custom post types, images, and so forth. Unless you have a copy of the database, the files you have will only be useful for setting up the same plugins and theme that were being used on the old host.

There may be a couple of ways to restore your lost content:

1. Check [Wayback Machine](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjqlYygou3SAhUO8GMKHeZvB8YQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Farchive.org%2Fweb%2F&usg=AFQjCNEN5v98hMy4RPfdZzngw-0g8JJiGw&sig2=JxZ9B_4EGyilXRVDENPBfw&bvm=bv.150475504,d.amc) - if it's a larger site it may be indexed here, and you can go through page by page and rebuild.
2. Check Google's cache - if the site was only recently removed from the old webhost, the individual pages may be cached for a time. It would be wise to download as "complete webpage" each page and then go through page by page and rebuild. Same with images - if they've only recently been removed, you may be able to find (possibly lower-resolution) cached versions and download them. To check, do a Google search for `site:http://example.com` (replace with your URL).

If neither of these exist, you'll need to start from scratch on the content, but you'll have learned a valuable lesson about backing up. :)