# How to import large sql files that would take more than 300s on phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I was trying to sql file - a big one (989MB) but I got this:

´Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php on line 261´

I even read the line 261

`return mysqli_query($link, $query, $method);`

I read the documentation - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=12&p=1&q=Fatal+error%3A+Maximum+execution+time+of+300+seconds+exceeded+in+C%3A%5Cxampp%5CphpMyAdmin%5Clibraries%5Cdbi%5CDBIMysqli.class.php+on+line+261 - but I wasn't able to find anything. That said, I'd need phpAdmin runs for 1 hour or even more

Is it possible to set that for infinite (no limit time)?

Edit - I got this > Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\import.lib.php on line 396.  I had set to 10000 and unchecked "Allow the interruption of an import in case the script detects it is close to the PHP timeout limit. "

Comment: Have you considered batch import? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26310424/2298301

Comment: No, thank you. Ill have a look.

Answer (score 1):

In [phpMyAdmin's config file](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html) there is a variable `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']` that sets the maximum execution time (in seconds).

Comment: Thank you so much, dude!

Comment: Is it possible to set that for infinite (no limit time)?

Comment: I think 0 is no limit

Comment: I got this > Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\import.lib.php on line 396.  I had set to 10000 and unchecked "Allow the interruption of an import in case the script detects it is close to the PHP timeout limit. "

Answer (score 1):

The setting is done in phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php as

> $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;

That being said, this file should not be updated, use phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php

Comment: Is it possible to set that for infinite (no limit time)?

Comment: @RyckRichards yes, set 0

Comment: I got this > Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\import.lib.php on line 396.  I had set to 10000 and unchecked "Allow the interruption of an import in case the script detects it is close to the PHP timeout limit. "

Comment: @RyckRichards Ah yes, the php settings.You might want to check the \xampp\php\php.ini for post_max_size, max_execution_time, max_input_time and upload_max_filesize. Or even better, don't rely on php at all. Open the folder xampp\mysql\bin in your command line and enter `mysql.exe -u username -p databaseName < hugeFile.sql`